# Missing JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION in php 5.6.8

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using php 5.6.8 on ubuntu 12.04, trying to `json_encode($arr, JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION)` but `JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION` is undefined. I thought maybe it was introduced in `php-json 1.3.7+`, so i tried to `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade php5-json`, it tells me i have the newest version of `php-json`.

I'm using [Ondřej Surý PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) as the source. Anyone have an idea what's wrong?

**Edit**

I've also checked in php without any application (`php -a`), this constant is still undefined. So i don't think it's anything app-related.

Comment: Are you within a namespace?

Comment: Yes, but i don't think it related, i've checked also with pure PHP interactive mode, the constant is still missing.

Comment: Probably an issue with the PPA you are using. Suggest you use https://deb.sury.org/#bug-reporting to ask the guy about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be available in [PHP 5.6.6+](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.6).

In case some of your tools complains about missing constant you can add polyfill:

```
if(!defined('JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION'))
{
    define('JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION', 1024);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its not solution...just some time saving stuff

```
function precise_round(num, decimals) {
   var t = Math.pow(10, decimals);   
   return (Math.round((num * t) + (decimals>0?1:0)*(Math.sign(num) * (10 / Math.pow(100, decimals)))) / t).toFixed(decimals);
}
```